# How to Access OWIN Connector after Startup in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, owin

I have a MVC project that uses OwinConnectorFactory and ConnectorBuilder in startup.cs to create a connector, using the passed-in IAppBuilder.  How do I access the connector after startup?  Let's say, during authentication?
  I've tried the http owin context but couldn't find connectors in request/response items.  I didn't know where else to look.
TIA

Answer (score 0):

One approach how to do it is via IoC, if you are using it in the project. Initialize you container right in the class marked by OwinStarutup attribute where all middle layers are wired up too. 
Add these instances into the container and leave DI to inject them where ever required.